# How to change child's parent in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have one stupid question. How can I change parent of the child in realm java-android with saving child's id. 
Should I get Bookmark from one parent. delete it. And create new one with the same id in other parent?

Thank you!

**UPDATED**

Or, if I understand correctly, I can delete from one parent's resultList child and add it to other's without creating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [realm's documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships) we can freely manipulate RealmList relations contents.

I've done in the following way:

```
new_category.getBookmarks().add(bookmark);
parent_category.getBookmarks().remove(bookmark);
```

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you!